# HDFS to RDBMS using Sqoop - table creation

Tags: mysql, hdfs, sqoop

I initially had **HBase** data which I exported to **HDFS** which generated a file named '`part-00000`'. Now, I want to export the **HDFS** into **MYSQL** using **Sqoop**.

I tried to run this Sqoop command,

```
**$ bin/sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db --table *bar*  --export-dir /var/hbadoop/hdfsdata/part-0000 --username root --password password -m 1**
```

It gave an error:

```
**Error manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException; Unknown intial character set index '224' received from server. Initial client character set can be forces via the 'characterEncoding' property.
      at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQlError.java.910)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.configureClientCharacterSet(Connection.java:2412)
      at ..**
```

Please note that I have **not** created a destination table 'bar' in MySQL to where I am planning to export HDFS data. I am not sure if I have to create a destination MYSQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar which was old from sqoop/lib directory and I downloaded the latest mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar and copied it to sqoop/lib folder and now I don't see "Unknown intial character set index '224' received from server." error anymore.

From searching on that error, the old mysql driver I downloaded had a bug(- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,139534,256214#msg-256214)